# Berkeley DB(Unable to Locate Component)

Tags: c++, berkeley-db

I have a problem with berkeley DB. I get a dialog titled "Unable To Locate Componenent" saying "This application has failed to start because libdb48.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem", then it crashes after clicking ok. I got the error message when running these simple code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <db_cxx.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Db db(0, 0);
}
```

I already set the Additional include directories to the "build_windows" directory and I have linked to the "libdb48.lib". I honestly do not know what to do here. The funny part is, I googled and I had 0 pages returned.

I am using visual studio c++ 2008 and Berkeley DB 4.8.24

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Where is libdb48.dll?  Is it installed?  Where?  A hackish solution that should make it work is to copy libdb48.dll into c:\windows\system32.  If that solves the problem, then you know that the DLL just wasn't on the path.  Then you can find a more appropriate place to put it.

Comment: +1 - the more appropriate place is probably the same directory as your output binary.